# Set Max & Min zoom level in React Native Maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

How to Set Min & Max Zoom level in React Native Maps

```
<MapView
    ref={(ref) => this.mapView = ref}
    clustering={true}
    clusterTextColor='#fff'
    style={styles.map}
    region={this.props.coordinate}
>
    //My map markers
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
<MapView
    minZoomLevel={2}  // default => 0
    maxZoomLevel={15} // default => 20
>
    //My map markers
</MapView>
```

All Component API in [This Link](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md).